# Creating a dynamic pivot table with percentages in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I am working in mySQL. I have a table ('offers') that has a number of of rows.  Each row relates to an offer at a particular date/time.  Each offer goes to a person, who will accept or decline the offer.  Sample data:

```
    offer_time              person      status
    2014-12-12 00:00:00     Bob         accepted
    2014-11-12 00:00:00     Jim         accepted
    2014-11-12 00:00:00     Bob         accepted
    2014-12-12 00:00:00     Jim         declined
    2014-11-12 00:00:00     Jim         declined
    2014-12-12 00:00:00     Bob         accepted
    2014-11-13 00:00:00     Jim         declined
    2014-12-13 00:00:00     Bob         accepted
    2014-11-13 00:00:00     Bob         accepted
    2015-11-13 00:00:00     Bob         declined
```

I would like to pivot this, so that for each person (there will more in the full dataset and their names will vary over time), I create a column showing the percentage of offers that they accept over time (by month/year).  This data will be used for graphing.

So far, I have:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'count(case when consultant = ''' ,
      consultant,
      ''' then 1 end) AS ',
      replace(consultant, ' ', '')
    )
    ) INTO @sql
FROM offers;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT MONTH(offer_time) as month, YEAR(offer_time) as year, ', @sql, ' from offers
group by MONTH(offer_time),YEAR(offer_time)');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

This gives the total number of offers for each person by month/year:

```
month   year    Jim     Bob
12      2014    1       3
11      2014    3       2
11      2015    0       1
```

Rather than counting the total number of rows (offers) for each person, I would like to calculate the percentage of the total offer count for each person that was accepted. I cannot work this out!  Thanks.

EDIT:

The output from the example data above should look something like:

```
month   year    Jim     Bob
12      2014    0       100
11      2014    33.33   100
11      2015    NA      0
```

(the NA comes from there being no offers to Jim in 2015).

EDIT2:

I can do this with a static pivot as follows:

```
SELECT
    MONTH(offer_time),
    YEAR (offer_time),
    COUNT(IF(person= 'Bob' AND status='accepted', 1, NULL)) / COUNT(IF(person= 'Bob', 1, NULL)) * 100 AS Bob,
    COUNT(IF(person = 'Jim' AND status='accepted', 1, NULL)) / COUNT(IF(person= 'Jim', 1, NULL)) * 100 AS Jim
FROM
    offers
GROUP BY
    MONTH(offer_time), YEAR(offer_time)
```

I just now need to figure out how to make it dynamic.

Comment: What should be the correct result based on the example data, can you work out a ascii text table?

Comment: *"Rather than counting the total number of rows (offers) for each person, I would like to calculate the percentage of the total offer count for each person that was accepted."*  I assume these counts should work by month, year as well?

Comment: I have added the expected output above.  Yes - the percentages should be by month/year as per the sample table.

Comment: I am getting closer - static version of solution added above...

Comment: which script you will use ? php ?

Comment: Eventually I will use the query in Laravel (PHP) to create JSON for chart.js.

Answer (score 0):

OK - I think I have it figured with a dynamic solution:

```
    SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
            CONCAT(' COUNT(IF(person= ''',
            person,
            ''' AND status = "accepted", offer_time, NULL)) / COUNT(IF(person= ''',
            person,
            ''', offer_time, NULL)) * 100 AS ',
            person
            )
        ) INTO @sql
        FROM offers;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT MONTH(offer_time) as month, YEAR(offer_time) as year, ', @sql, ' from offers
    group by MONTH(offer_time),YEAR(offer_time)');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Keep in mind this might give a syntax error on larger groups (more unique person added) as GROUP_CONCAT has a limit of 1024 and truncates after which most likely will result into invalid SQL.  You have to make sure to use `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;`  before using GROUP_CONAT

Comment: Thanks.  I should have no more than 10-15 persons at any one time.